# General Guidance For Saving Quantity Fields in a busy system

Tags: database

Suppose I have a traditional sales/inventory system with an Inventory object that has a quantity property.

If I were to use something like NHibernate to persist my object's state back to the database wouldn't it be possible, in a busy system, from the time NHibernate loaded the object from the database and set the quantity to 5 that someone could have received a PO in the system and updated the quantity to 10?

So when my code deducts quantity from a sale of that item I would possibly set the quantity to 4 instead of 9?

Wouldn't it be safer to issue an update to the database that just says, whatever the quantity currently is, subtract 1.

That doesn't seem to fit well in an object model scenario though.

Has anyone had to deal with this type of issue before?

Thanks

Comment: You might wanna search for how to deal with concurrency in NHibernate. It is possible to generate and keep locks to make sure every action gets executed in the correct order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to wrap your read and write in a transaction. This is exactly the sort of problem they were designed to prevent, and many ORMs expose the ability to start and end a transaction.

As with any abstraction, there's always the question of efficiency. It's possible the ORM will not generate SQL queries that are as efficient as `UPDATE count = count - 1 FROM products WHERE product.id = 1 AND product.count > 1` which would not require a transaction.

Comment: This makes sense, if your UI loads the entity that is being worked with, wouldn't there be some time in between the read and the write?  I imagine at the time of saving you could read the object again to get it's current state?

Comment: Say you have a webpage that allows you to view the current quantity of a thing, and has a number field, and a button that reduces the quantity by that #. When you display the page to the user, you load the quantity, no transaction needed, since this is a read. When the user types something in the field and hits #, you're in a new "request" to the webpage, so you read/write using an ORM with a transaction, or you directly issue the query I showed. You then listen for transaction OR query failing, and let the user know in your response--this means the count changed since the page was generated.